# How do i view decades in javafx DatePicker?

Tags: javafx, datepicker

So if someone is born in 1980 and they want to enter their age through mouse they would have to click on the year arrow 37 times, which is pretty ludicrous.

Is there a way to view the decades in the javafx datepicker so that the user can just choose and option like 1980-1990 and pick a date?

Edit: since no ones answered this yet i'll just post an image for clarity

https://ibb.co/exrVgQ

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to do it in the existing datepicker, but you can have a workaround, have 2 buttons  - `nextDecade` and `prevDecade` and set the date of the datepicker using `calendar.set(int field, int value);` on click of these buttons, I can make this as an answer with the code if this works for you

Comment: sure that would be great thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
public class JavaFxTest extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Button prevDecade=new Button("Previous Decade");
    Button nextDecade=new Button("Next Decade");
    DatePicker datePicker=new DatePicker();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.of(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));

    prevDecade.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

            LocalDate value = datePicker.getValue();
            datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.of(value.getYear()-10, value.getMonth(), value.getDayOfMonth()));
            datePicker.show();
        }
    });

    nextDecade.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            datePicker.show();
            LocalDate value = datePicker.getValue();
            datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.of(value.getYear()+10, value.getMonth(), value.getDayOfMonth()));

        }
    });
    HBox hBox=new HBox();
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(datePicker, prevDecade, nextDecade);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hBox,500,300));

    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

But the only problem is that datepicker hides the calendar when the buttons are clicked, so we have to explicitly do `datepicker.show()`, may be theres a way to fix this, or a better way to approach your problem, this is all I could think of :)